# JSON parsing through GSON returns null values

Tags: java, json

I am trying to read the values of a JSON output.

This is the JSON output:

```
{"nameOfSummoner":{"id":56529189,"name":"test","profileIconId":550,"summonerLevel":30,"revisionDate":1422110739000}}
```

And with the following code I am trying to read it:

```
    final Connector connector = new Connector();
    String response = connector.connect("link"); // (Returns a String value of the JSON)

    final Gson gson = new Gson();
    final Summoner summoner = gson.fromJson(response, Summoner.class); //Summoner is a model class
    System.out.println(summoner);
```

Summoner class:

```
public class Summoner {

private String name;
private long profileIconId;
private long summonerLevel;
private long revisionDate;

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(final String name) {
    this.name = name;
}

public long getProfileIconId() {
    return profileIconId;
}

public void setProfileIconId(final long profileIconId) {
    this.profileIconId = profileIconId;
}

public long getSummonerLevel() {
    return summonerLevel;
}

public void setSummonerLevel(final long summonerLevel) {
    this.summonerLevel = summonerLevel;
}

public long getRevisionDate() {
    return revisionDate;
}

public void setRevisionDate
        (long revisionDate) {
    this.revisionDate = revisionDate;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "Summoner{" +
            "name='" + name + '\'' +
            ", profileIconId=" + profileIconId +
            ", summonerLevel=" + summonerLevel +
            ", revisionDate=" + revisionDate +
            '}';
}
```

}

And I get the following output on the console:

```
Summoner{name='null', profileIconId=0, summonerLevel=0, revisionDate=0}
```

I have sadly no idea why this happens. Any help I get is appreciated. I am fairly sure it has to do with the JSON output that "nameOfSummoner" is on top and maybe that's why it does not read what is below.

Comment: can you provide the contents of your Summoner class as well? Gson expects exact model to parse the json

Comment: Can you post the `Summoner` class also.

Comment: Your input is a map with 1 key/value pair. The key is "nameOfSummoner" and the value seems to be a `Summoner`. Did you catch or ignore any Exception ?

Comment: check the value of response might be it coming as empty dur to which object have it's default value of all it's variable

Comment: Thank you all for commenting. I have added the Summoner class. Edit: There are no exceptions being thrown in the console just the attributes with no value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentioned by @PeterMmm , your input is a map with 1 key-value pair.

You need to Create another POJO with Summoner object as attribute:

```
public class Sample {

private Summoner nameOfSummoner;

//getters and setters

}
```

and then try parsing. Or, you could create a Map and parse.

```
Map<String, Summoner> responseObj = new HashMap<String, Summoner>();

responseObj= gson.fromJson(response, responseObj.class);

Summoner obj = responseObj.get("nameOfSummoner");
```

You will also need to have "id" attribute in Summoner class I believe, else gson will throw an exception.